# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object - angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service call that makes a call to an API to return JSON. I then have a function with a subscribe that calls the service call. The JSOON is returned fine and the service call and subscribe all work. However, upon building my application in its build pipeline, I get the following error **"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object."** and my build fails (even though it works fine locally and passes all tests). I am using angular 9 and typescript.

My subscribe and the function that it's in look as such:

```
houseData: HouseValueObject;
houseNumber = '12345';

callHouseService() {
   this.streetHouseService.getHouseData(this.houseNumber).subscribe(
     async (data) => {
       this.houseData = await data;
       const keys = Object.keys(this.houseData.extensiveHouseData);
       this.extensiveHouseDataList = keys.map(k => this.houseData.extensiveHouseData[k]);
}
)
}
```

The getHouseData method looks as such:

```
export class HouseService {
  private readonly relativeURL = 'services/api/houseinfo/'
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  
  getHouseData(houseNumber: string): Observable<HouseValueObject> {
   return.this.http.get<HouseValueObject>(this.relativeURL + houseNumber + '/');
}
}
}
```

The value object for HouseValueObject looks as such:

```
export class HouseValueObject {
   numberBathrooms: number;
   extensiveHouseData: HouseValue[];
}
```

I thought adding the async and await would suspend execution until the returned promise is fulfilled so that the JSON data would be delivered to **const keys = Object.keys...**
line of code would work, but that does not appear to be the case. My question is, how can I correctly go about suspending execution until the returned promise is fulfilled to ensure the JSON data exists and the **const keys = Object.keys...** line of code works as it does locally?

Comment: Using async/await inside a subscribe looks suspicious. Can you post your `getHouseData` method?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I have added the getHouseData method per your request.

Comment: `async`/`await` used in a subscribe (which already handles asynchronism) is clearly useless and error prone. However your mistake may not come from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personaly would rewrite the service to return a promise, should be easier to read.

`HouseService`:

```
getHouseData(houseNumber: string): Promise<HouseValueObject> {
   return this.http
      .get<HouseValueObject>(`${this.relativeURL}${houseNumber}/`)
      .toPromise<HouseValueObject>();
}
```

`Component`:

```
async callHouseService(): Promise<void> {
  this.houseData = await his.streetHouseService.getHouseData(this.houseNumber);
  this.extensiveHouseDataList = Object
    .keys(this.houseData.extensiveHouseData)
    .map(k => this.houseData.extensiveHouseData[k]);
}
```